# Hyperbox fail to run hypervisor

Tags: hypervisor, hyperbox

I could not start the hypervisor in my [Hyperbox](https://kamax.io/hbox/) client regardless what type of Connector ID that I used. The status will also fail.

I have tried using the [portable version](https://github.com/hyperbox/hyperbox/releases/download/0.0.10/hbox-0.0.10-win_amd64-server.zip) and the [installer version](https://github.com/hyperbox/hyperbox/releases/download/0.0.10/hbox-0.0.10-win_amd64-server.exe) for the server but the client just could not connect to the hypervisor.

I tried the following scenario but it fail to connect to the hypervisor:

- server on the localhost machine (Windows 32-bits OS) and the client on the localhost machine with firewall totally disable.
- server on a another machine (Windows 64-bits OS) and the client still on the localhost machine with firewall totally disable.

I have followed the instruction in their webpage as shown below:

```
Download Server
Install Server
Ensure Hyperbox Server Service is started
Download Client
Install Client
Run Client
Configure client and connect to installed server
```

Please enlighten me how to find the exact problem why I cannot start the hypervisor and connect to it.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am the creator of Hyperbox and I only notice your question now. Didn't expect people to ask here!

To answer your question: the bit missing in the doc is that on Windows, you also need to start the VirtualBox WebServices server so Hyperbox can connect to it.
If you already have a user with VMs you want to manage, you need to start it with that user (I would guess yours here).

Open a prompt and:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
vboxwebsrv -A null
```

Then in the Hyperbox client, go back to the dialog in the screenshot, select "Oracle VirtualBox - vbox-x.y-ws" and connect.
x and y stands for your version of VirtualBox. Latest release (0.12) supports 4.2, 4.3 and 5.0.

Connecting via WebServices takes several seconds and you should see a task appear in the bottom list of the main window. You should also see some activity in the command prompt where the web service is running.
Once successfully connected, the server icon in the left panel will turn green and VMs will be listed if you have any registered under that user.

Next version (0.13) that should come out in January 2016 will automatically create its own webservices process and provide a better presentation of the available hypervisors!